# Парсинг Excel файл

Tags: python, парсер, excel, обработка-данных

Как парсить Excel файл с помощью Python и взять данные именно с нужных столбцов?

Comment: [вот](https://habr.com/company/otus/blog/331998/) тут все написано, максимально полно

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Пример с использованием модуля [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd   # pip install pandas

df = pd.read_excel(r'D:\download\1.xls', sheet_name='Лист1')
print(df)
```

вывод:

```
  Артикул Наименование  Тариф (прайс) на 12.06.83
0    а123      Товар А                        100
1    б123      Товар Б                        200
2    в123      Товар В                        300
```

в виде обычных Vanilla Python списков или Numpy Array:

```
In [20]: df['Артикул'].tolist()
Out[20]: ['а123', 'б123', 'в123']

In [21]: df.values
Out[21]:
array([['а123', 'Товар А', 100],
       ['б123', 'Товар Б', 200],
       ['в123', 'Товар В', 300]], dtype=object)

In [22]: df.values.tolist()
Out[22]: [['а123', 'Товар А', 100], ['б123', 'Товар Б', 200], ['в123', 'Товар В', 300]]

In [23]: df.T.values.tolist()
Out[23]: [['а123', 'б123', 'в123'], ['Товар А', 'Товар Б', 'Товар В'], [100, 200, 300]]
```

PS Pandas поддерживает работу с XLSX и XLS форматами и умеет использовать следующие модули:

- xlrd, xlwt
- openpyxl
- xlsxwriter

Answer (score 3):

Вот эта библиотека решит ваши вопросы: [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Вот пример кода, как можно работать с xlsx

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook('/tmp/data.xlsx', use_iterators=True)
first_sheet = workbook.get_sheet_names()[0]
worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(first_sheet)

for row in worksheet.iter_rows():
    print row

# check out the last row
for cell in row:
    print cell
```

Там же вы сможете найти полный tutorial как ей пользоваться и как читать нужные страницы и ячейки.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Исправил с учетом требований.